# Content is not allowed in prolog, when trying to use 'put' method using requests module python

Tags: python, python-requests, put

I'm trying to write some script using requests module in Python 3.5.

I have no problem using 'get' but when I try to use 'put',  with right headers , it gives me 'Content is not allowed in prolog' error.

I've looked through the web to find the solution but I can't diagnose the exact problem.

```
import requests
headers = {'Content-type': 'application/xml', 'Accept': 'text/string'}


req = requests.put("https://test.com/api/v2/samples/xxxxx", headers = headers,data = {'name':'john'},auth=('user', 'password'))
```

and this throws

```
<Response [400]>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<exc:exception xmlns:exc="http://test.com/ri/exception">
    <message>Content is not allowed in prolog.</message>
</exc:exception>
```

Thanks,

Comment: But you are not passing xml? Are you really just using  `{'name':'john'}`?

Comment: @ padraic , yea I'm just using that